# Postgres SQL SELECT data from the table the entry exists with ID

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have the following scenario.I have 3 tables with the following structure.

```
TABLE A
 -entry_id (PRIMARY KEY, INTEGER)

TABLE B 
 -entry_id (FOREIGN_KEY -> TABLE A)
 -content (TEXT)

TABLE C
  -entry_id (FOREIGN_KEY -> TABLE A)
  -content (INTEGER)
```

I want to retrive the content cell value from either table B or table C. The value can be in just one of the table. So it is either table B or C witch have an entry with a given `entry_id`.

PS. Sorry if duplicate did not manage to find anything to match what i need.

Comment: Would like something that works with also a 4th table. For example:    
 TABLE D
  -entry_id (FOREIGN_KEY -> TABLE A)
  -content (DOUBLE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand, you need something like:

```
select entry_id, content::text from TABLEB where entry_id = ?
union all
select entry_id, content::text from TABLEC where entry_id = ?
union all
select entry_id, content::text from TABLED where entry_id = ?
```

Comment: No my problem is that i have an entry_id and the value for that entry_id can  be in any of the 3 tables(a value can only be in one table for and entry_id).So i want based on the entry_id to retrive the corespondent data from one of the other 3 tables.Does it make sense?

Comment: @Cosmin_Victor - then add `where` clause to all query, please check edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

If it can only exist in one table at a time, use a union

```
select a1.entry_id, b2.content
from TableA a1
inner join TableB b2
on a1.entry_id = b2.entry_id

union -- This removes any duplicates. Use UNION ALL to show duplicates

select a1.entry_id, c3.content::text
from TableA a1
inner join TableC c3
on a1.entry_id = c3.entry_id
```

Comment: `UNION` will remove duplicates, why you predicate "only exist in one table at a time"?..

Comment: 1) UNION types integer and text cannot be matched.